# CNN-LSTM Image Classification

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Is it possible to reshape 512x512 rgb image to (timestep, dim)? Otherwards, I am trying to convert this reshape layer: `Reshape((23, 3887))` to 512 vice 299. Also, is there any documentation explaining how to determine input_dim and timestep for Keras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your problem is similar to one that i had earlier today. Look at it here: [Keras functional API: Combine CNN model with a RNN to to look at sequences of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488768/keras-functional-api-combine-cnn-model-with-a-rnn-to-to-look-at-sequences-of-im)

Now to add to the answer from the question i linked too. Let `number_of_images` be `n`. In your case the original data format would be `(n, 512, 512, 3)`. All you then need to do decide how many images you want per sequence. Say you want a sequence of 5 images and have gotten 5000 images in total. Then reshaping to `(1000, 5, 512, 512, 3)` should do. This way the model sees 1000 sequences of 5 images.