# How to use Conv2D and LSTM layers with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a model which works with **Conv2D** using Keras but I would like to **add a LSTM** layer. This is the data I am using:

- x_train with shape (13984, **334, 35, 1**)
- y_train with shape (13984, **5**)

My model without LSTM is:

```
inputs = Input(name='input',shape=(334,35,1))
layer = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3,activation='relu',data_format='channels_last')(inputs)
layer = Flatten()(layer)
predictions = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(layer)
network = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
network.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What is **the correct way of adding a LSTM** layer just before the Dense layer?

I tried to use TimeDistributed or Reshape/Permute but I always get errors.

Comment: You can simply adopt a reshape operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789979/10375049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method explained by the user deKeijzer works. I found another way to solve the problem. It is to use a Reshape layer (reshaping by (334,35)) just after the last Conv2D layer and then add LSTM layers.

Comment: What do you mean by reshaping by (334,35)? Do you mean reshape the last conv layer from the cnn part?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question is similar to one that i had yesterday. The answer can be found here: [Keras functional API: Combine CNN model with a RNN to to look at sequences of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488768/keras-functional-api-combine-cnn-model-with-a-rnn-to-to-look-at-sequences-of-im)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried your method. I just have two questions:  I get an error for the Dense model "The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape`". Which input_shape should we use? And how do you reshape your data for the `main_input`?